# Asp.net Web API | Document Upload Async await or Task.Run

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've asp.net web API integrated with public ui web site

the website will have many concurrent users  that submit applications , api pull this to database.

the API do a lot functions like :

- Get Data
- Update Data
- Upload files

I'm trying to use Async operations ( specially in upload documents )

I edited all function to use await Task.Run()=>bla())) , like this :

```
if (Someconditions)
{
await Task.Run(() => Function1());
await Task.Run(() => Function2())
if (Someconditions)
await Task.Run(() => Function3())

if (Someconditions)
await Task.Run(() => CreateUpdateDocumentDetails)); // Uploading document
```

For document upload function , I'm very confused

Should  I use `await UploadDocumentAsync()` or

```
Task.Run(()=>UploadDocumetSync()) or Task.Run(()=>UploadDocumentAsync())
```

Also Does Task.Run(SyncFunc())  mean all above function runs asynchronously without marked them as async  and is it good practice?

Last questions what's the difference between this and making all functions (async / await)

Comment: It's usually a bad sign of poor design when you are calling `Task.Run()` inside an web API request handler -- especially when using a conventional controller or request handler shipped with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

1 .It's an uploading process better is Async

2 .Use `Task.Run(()=>UploadDocumentAsync());`

3 .Async tells caller, I am an asynchronous method, don't wait for me.await inside the Task() ask for waiting for an asynchronous task.

for example after running below program will wait 10 seconds to show the task done.

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
     Task();
     System.Console.WriteLine("main thread is running while waiting");
     Console.ReadLine();
}
private static async void Task(){
     await Task.Delay(10000);
     Console.WriteLine("Waited for 10s");
}
```

Comment: thank you for clarification , what happens if  use Task.Run()=>SyncMethod()) , will this occurs async or as the original function is sync , it will run sync and ignore task